# Downloading Sentinel 2 Float32 Image as NPY array in GEE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, numpy, google-earth-engine-python-api

[image]

I am trying to download an Sentinel 2 image with 12 bands. The 'Precision Type' of the Image is 'Float'.
When I try to download the image in Int format it is downloaded perfectly. However, when trying to download as 'float'. The values are converted into 'inf' value.

The following is my code snippet:

```
import ee
import requests
import numpy as np
import io

# Trigger the authentication flow.
ee.Authenticate()
# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize(opt_url='https://earthengine-highvolume.googleapis.com')


# user input, please modify all your inputs here if you want to do analysis for different aoi or timeframe

# Define the study  period
# The code will analyze images only for the months within from_month to to_month for each years
from_year = 2023
to_year = 2023
from_month = 1
to_month = 12
maximum_cloud = 10 #cloud cover to filter the images in percentage

mgrs_tile_no = '48PVT' # For the area of our interest mgrs tile no is 48PVT. For different aoi please check sentinel 2 docs

aoi_ee  = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-kazijahid/assets/Chaba_extent")

# Sentinel 2 Imagery collection

'Using sentinel 2 Harmonized Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-2A product.Details about the productcan\
be found on the link https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR_HARMONIZED'

S2_SR_Harmonized = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')\
.filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '48PVT')\
    .filterBounds(aoi_ee)\
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(from_year,to_year,'year'))\
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(from_month,to_month,'month'))\
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 70))\
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('DARK_FEATURES_PERCENTAGE', 1)) # We are filutring the dark feature with a threshold of 1
                                                        #to reduce time we are checking the image of only on the tiles where aoi located

print("Total Sentinel2 SR Image Retrieved: ",S2_SR_Harmonized.size().getInfo())

bestCloudImage = S2_SR_Harmonized.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',True).first() # Sorting the image on cloudcover and taking the best image

# Functions
def cloudMaskingBasedonSCL(img_cloudy):
    scl = img_cloudy.select('SCL')
    #Selecting Cloudy Mask
    img_cloudy_shadow = img_cloudy.select('SCL').eq([3])
    img_cloudy_low = img_cloudy.select('SCL').eq([7])
    img_cloudy_med = img_cloudy.select('SCL').eq([8])
    img_cloudy_high = img_cloudy.select('SCL').eq([9])
    img_cloudy_cirrus = img_cloudy.select('SCL').eq([10])
    
    
    cloud_mask = img_cloudy_shadow.add(img_cloudy_low).add(img_cloudy_med).add(img_cloudy_high).add(img_cloudy_cirrus) 
    

#     #Inverting the Mask
    invert_mask = cloud_mask.eq(0).selfMask() #invert mask will have the pixels with only no cloud
    cloud_mask_only = cloud_mask.eq(1).selfMask() #this will have only the pixels without cloud
        
    img_masked = img_cloudy.updateMask(invert_mask)
    img_unmasked = img_masked.unmask(-99999)
    img_cloudy_cloudless = img_unmasked
    
    return img_cloudy_cloudless


def functn_scale_bands(image, bandstoscale, scalefactor):
    
    scaledbands = image.select(bandstoscale).multiply(scale_factor)
    
    return image.addBands(scaledbands, overwrite=True)

def functn_ResemapleSentinel2(img):
    'Function to resample the sentinel bands from there native scale to 10 meter scale. Takes the image as iput, return the resampled image'
    crs =  img.select('B1').projection().crs()
    img = img.resample('bilinear').reproject(crs=crs, scale=10)
    return img


def functn_Clip(img, aoi_ee):
    'Cliping the bands of the image to the area of interest. Takes the image and aoi feature as input and returns the clipped image.'
    clipped_img = img.clip(aoi_ee)
    return clipped_img


#CloudMasking
print('Applying cloud mask')
bestCloudImageCloudMasked = cloudMaskingBasedonSCL(bestCloudImage) # applying the cloud mask
print('Applying cloud mask done')

bandnames = bestCloudImageCloudMasked.bandNames() # Retrieving the bandnames 
#Scaling the selected bands
selectedbands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12']
# scale_factor = 1 # Define the scale factor
scale_factor = 0.0001 # Define the scale factor
print('Scaling the bands',selectedbands, 'by factor', scale_factor)
bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaled = functn_scale_bands(bestCloudImageCloudMasked, selectedbands, scale_factor) # Scaling the selected layers of cloudmasked image
print('Scaling done')

print('Resampling the masked and scaled image')
bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampled = functn_ResemapleSentinel2(bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaled) #reseampled to 10m 
print('Resampling done')

print('Clipping the image')
bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampledClipped = functn_Clip(bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampled,aoi_ee) #clipped to aoi
print('clipping done')

selectedbands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12']
bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampledClipped_SB = bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampledClipped.select(selectedbands)

bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampledClipped_SB_f=bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampledClipped_SB.toFloat()

#Some meta info of the image that will be useful for later calculatiosn
projection =  bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaled.select('B1').projection()
crs = projection.crs()
transform_image = projection.transform()


# Downloading the Final bands image chunk as a NumPy structured array.
bandsData = []
failedBands = []
selectedbands=['B1']
for band in selectedbands:

    thisBand = bestCloudImageCloudMaskedScaledResampledClipped_SB_f.select(band)   
    
    try:
        urlNumpy = thisBand.getDownloadUrl({
            'scale': 10,
            'crs': crs,
            'region': aoi_ee.geometry(),
            'format': 'NPY'
        })
        
        responseNumpy= requests.get(urlNumpy)
        dataNumpy = np.load(io.BytesIO(responseNumpy.content), encoding='bytes').astype(np.float64)

        bandsData.append(dataNumpy)
    except Exception as e:
        failedBands.append(thisBand)
        print("An exception occurred while downloading band:", band)
        print(str(e))
        
print(bandsData)
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. Make your script complete and executable while boiling it down to the bare minimum (e.g. no progress bar, single band download).

Comment: @DanielWiell Hi, I added a working snippet to reproduce the issue. Can you please check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are simply the values of the masked pixel you're seeing. You are always downloading the bounds of the region and in your case, the values visible in the cropped Numpy array are simply all masked out.

The value of the middle pixel is OK, for instance:

```
print(dataNumpy[round(len(dataNumpy) / 2)][round(len(dataNumpy[0]) / 2)])
```